# PHP - prevent overwriting data in a file

Tags: php, file, overwrite

I have created a simple databaseless CMS. When saving a file, the PHP opens the corresponding file, adds the new data, and closes the file (using file_put_contents).

This all works well - until the same file is saved twice (or more) simultaneously. By which I mean when a file_put_contents function is started on a file that is already experiencing another file_put_contents function. In this case, only the changes for the second file_put_contents are saved to the file.

So my question is - is there a way of checking if a file is already being written to, and waiting until it has finished being written to, before starting the second file_put_contents?

Comment: Out of curiousity why not use a database? For your question I think this function might help you `filectime()`

Comment: What you want is certainly possible, but seriously use a database instead.

Comment: you can use `flock` to lock a file.

Comment: @Daan - speed, simplicity (at least theoretically), especially as most of my projects only need small amounts of data. A database would be overkill for these small projects.

Comment: @rwacarter The solution is to use `flock` as @lolka_bolka suggests. But I would go for sqlite database instead, it's file based, and manages this for you.

Comment: This is multithreading issue. Although `flock` might help you, but I'd suggest you look into thread synchronisation.

Comment: If you are using arrays, you can control the version with a timestamp index, and merge (array_merge) the content before save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `LOCK_EX` support was added to [`file_put_contents`](https://php.net/file-put-contents) in PHP 5.1 which will wait until any other lock on the file is released before writing to it. You can easily test this yourself.

## lock.php

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

$h = fopen(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "lock.txt", "c");

register_shutdown_function(function () use ($h) {
    fclose($h);
});

flock($h, LOCK_EX);
while (true);
```

## put.php

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

$f = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "lock.txt";

file_put_contents($f, "foo", LOCK_EX);

echo file_get_contents($f) , PHP_EOL;
```

## Test

Put both scripts in the same directory and open two shells. Execute `lock.php` in shell one and keep it open, execute `put.php` in shell two and you'll see that it is waiting, because an exclusive write lock was acquired by the other script for the file. Now go back to shell one and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> to abort execution (you may close the shell) and go back to your second shell. It should output `foo` and the script should terminate.

## Important

Reading of the file is not locked for this file, if this is a requirement use [`flock`](https://php.net/flock) since it supports all operations (`LOCK_SH | LOCK_EX`).

## SQLite

[PDO SQLite](https://php.net/pdo-sqlite) would give you the ability to work with simple text files as your database and take care of problems like locking for you. If you need to work with a lot of files and data consider using it as it features everything you need out of the box.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be almost exactly what I was looking for. However, in this example, one script locks the file while the other attempts to write to it. How can I adapt this so that the same script locks the file while it is writing to it? I tried a few things but nothing seemed to work.

Comment: The same thing happens if you start the same script more than once, but do not forget that these scripts are ultra fast, you need to write **a lot** of data in order to observe the lock. You could try with the following line: `file_put_contents("lock.txt", openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(1e9), LOCK_EX);` This generates 1 GB of random data and writes it to the file. Just start them almost at the same time and, well, wait. :P